# How do I read configuration settings from Symfony2 config.yml in twig template?

Tags: symfony, twig

In controller i can read like this

`$this->container->getParameter('test');`

But how get this var "test" in my twig template?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Depends what you need to get, my way of getting data from `parameters.ini` is:

**config.yml**

```
twig:
    globals: 
        google_maps_api_key: %google_maps_api_key%
```

**parameters.ini**

```
[parameters]
    google_maps_api_key="authkey"
```

in template:

`{{ google_maps_api_key }}`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can create your own Twig extension, in this class you can override `getGlobals()` and return an array with your global variables.

Or you can create a Twig method in this extension `param($value)` to return the right parameter.

Comment: While the other answer _would_ work (and is quicker) - this is (usually) the correct thing to do.