# How to get %secret% parameter in a listener in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, parameters

I am using Symfony 2.1.7 and I have overriden `UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener` class for login purposes. I want to get the value of symfony's secret parameter (set in `parameters.yml`) in this listener class. How can I achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I read configuration settings from Symfony2 config.yml in twig template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607956/how-do-i-read-configuration-settings-from-symfony2-config-yml-in-twig-template)

Comment: I don't think so, may be it is a kind of [Symfony2: How to get a config parameter within a listener?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425583/symfony2-how-to-get-a-config-parameter-within-a-listener) but i did not write my own listener, just override, and do not know the parameters provided for construction. I am asking if there is sth like container as in a controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where you declare the listener ( service.yml |xml ) you can add container as a constructor parameter , and then from container, you can call

```
$container->getParameter('secret');
```

Or other option is, that you can pass the parameter itself at the declaration with %secret%

Comment: Up to now, i had just override the method, but not the service.xml yet. When i override service.xml of the listener, I have added %kernel.secret% as the last parameter of the __construct() method (only parameter, no need the whole conainer) to the service. Now I can access parameter easily. Thx for the idea, now i have different visions ;)

Comment: That's true, if you doesn't need anything else, then you can do it like that, but most of the time, it's handy to have the container.